# GAE Keep Socket Alive

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to create a TCP connection in AppEngine (on the server side) and keep it alive indefinitely (or at least ~30 minutes). I've created a background thread, opened a `java.net.Socket` and attempted to read a line with a wrapped `BufferedReader`. After about 3 seconds of inactivity, I get the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket operation timed out: The API call remote_socket.Receive() took too long to respond and was cancelled.
```

I'll include a skeleton of the code I'm using below. Any help would be greatly appreciated (including workarounds or information on the limitations of sockets in GAE). Thanks!

```java
    ThreadFactory tm = ThreadManager.backgroundThreadFactory();
    thread = tm.newThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);
                socket.setSoTimeout(0);
                socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

                String in = reader.readLine();
                // execution never gets past here
                //...
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                // ... <close socket>
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

In case it's relevant, here's the use case: I've got a TCP server that used to work with an embedded Applet on the client side. I'd like to redesign the Applet as a webapp, but the server still works fine, so I'd rather not change it. I'd like to write a simple servlet that keeps the TCP connection alive and feeds messages back and forth between the TCP server and the GWT client.

Comment: That's probably not going to work. What's your use case? We could think about alternatives with other Google Cloud products

Comment: I added a description - see the last paragraph above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets have **lots of restrictions in GAE** due to security reasons, though GAE provides many ready to use services which requires use of sockets **like for email, xmpp etc**.

First your app needs to be paid app, **means billing must be enabled for using sockets on GAE**

You can have a [**look here for how to use sockets in java on GAE**](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-sockets-python-java-go/blob/master/java_socket_demo/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/demos/sockets/WhoIsClientServlet.java)

Below is the **excerpt from google app engine documentation for socket limitations**:

> App Engine supports sockets without requiring you to import any
>   special App Engine libraries or add any special App Engine code.
>   However, there are certain limitations and behaviors you need to be
>   aware of when using sockets:
>
> ```
> Sockets are available only for paid apps.
> You cannot create a listen socket; you can only create outbound sockets.
> java.net.URL is still configured to use the URL Fetch API; there is currently no way around this.
> Most classes in javax.net.ssl are supported.
> You can only use TCP or UDP; arbitrary protocols are not allowed.
> You cannot bind to specific IP addresses or ports.
> Port 25 (SMTP) is blocked; you can still use authenticated SMTP on the submission port 587.
> Private, broadcast, multicast, and Google IP ranges (except those whitelisted below), are blocked:
>     Google Public DNS: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 2001:4860:4860::8888, 2001:4860:4860::8844 port 53
>     Gmail SMTPS: smtp.gmail.com port 465 and 587
>     Gmail POP3S: pop.gmail.com port 995
>     Gmail IMAPS: imap.gmail.com port 993
> Socket descriptors are associated with the App Engine app that created them and are non-transferable (cannot be used by other apps).
> Sockets may be reclaimed after 2 minutes of inactivity; any socket operation keeps the socket alive for a further 2 minutes.
> You cannot Select between multiple available sockets because that requires java.nio.SocketChannel which is not currently supported.)
> ```

Comment: This mostly answers my question. The code you provide doesn't seem to offer a way around the 3s timeout, though (notice I am using ``setSoTimeout()``). Correct me if I missed it.

Comment: i guess u missed it. On line number:76 it is using setSoTimeout(10000).  Socket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.